# python SocketIO-client and nodejs socket.io server namespace mismatch

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, namespaces

My backend (nodejs) server defines a new namespace by `var clients = io.of('/clients')`. It looks something like this:

```
clients.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('descriptor', function(data) {
        // do something cool here
    }
});
```

My python client looks something like this:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, 

class ClientNameSpace(BaseNamespace):

    def on_connect(self):
        logger.info("connected")
        socketIO.emit("descriptor", "some cool data")

socketIO = SocketIO('127.0.0.1', 80)
clientSocket = socketIO.define(ClientNameSpace, '/clients')
socketIO.wait()
```

Running this code, **the descriptor method in the server never gets called** (I assume to it not being in the `/clients` namespace). But I can't use `clientSocket` inside `ClientNameSpace` as it says it is not defined. I assume the class gets activated as soon as the `SocketIO()` constructor gets activated and `clientSocket` does not get created until after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have set things up properly. try calling emit on clientSocket instead and also I think its a requirement to have at least one callback defined, not sure if that's still the case. So define a clientSocket.on("method name",callback);